# Excuting text via linux shell

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, paste

is there any way in linux command ,when i give the list text 

`aaaaaaaaaa.htm 4
bbbbbbbbbb.htm 5
....`

it will give me the result

`aaaaaaaaaa_2.htm
aaaaaaaaaa_3.htm
aaaaaaaaaa_4.htm
bbbbbbbbbb_2.htm
bbbbbbbbbb_3.htm
bbbbbbbbbb_4.htm
bbbbbbbbbb_5.htm
...`

Thanks much for any helps !

Comment: Yes, there should be a way.  Did you attempt anything to get the desired result?

Comment: You want to generate file names with 2 through the number added as a suffix before the extension?

Comment: Why? Smacks of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: ị am a new to linux shell ,in this situation ,i dont have a clue,can you help me to figure it out

Comment: We already figured out that you are new and want help. We can help you better if we understand your end goal. You want to generate this list of file names because...?

Comment: Thanks Broslow and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
cat list.txt 
aaaaaaaaaa.htm 4
bbbbbbbbbb.htm 5
awk '{gsub(/.htm/,"",$1);for (i = 2; i<=$2;i++){printf "%s_%s.htm\n",$1,i}}' list.txt 
aaaaaaaaaa_2.htm
aaaaaaaaaa_3.htm
aaaaaaaaaa_4.htm
bbbbbbbbbb_2.htm
bbbbbbbbbb_3.htm
bbbbbbbbbb_4.htm
bbbbbbbbbb_5.htm
```

Comment: +1 for teasing out an answerable problem; doesn't make much difference with the specific input, but you probably want `/\.htm/`. Slight optimization: `awk -F'\.htm' '{for(i=2;i<=$2;i++){printf "%s_%s%s\n",$1,i,FS}}' list.txt`

Comment: `awk -F".htm" '{for(i=2;i<=$2;i++){printf "%s_%s%s\n",$1,i,FS}}' list.txt`